# Is the epicenter always directly above the hypocenter?

Tags: geophysics, earthquakes

All the graphics I've seen showing epicenters with a hypocenter (labeled focus in the graph below) appear to show that epicenters are always directly above their related hypocenters. Is this correct?

[image: 3D slice of Earth showing a Earthquake with the related fault, epicenter, and hypocenter]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By definition, the answer is *yes*:

> epicenter, the point on the earth's surface vertically above the focus of an earthquake, or the Hypocenter

according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epicenter) or a many other sources.

Comment: Yes to the question - by definition :-) :-)

Answer (score 5):

Generally defined, an epicentre is just a projection of the hypocentre (aka focus), on the nearest outer surface of the body in which the seismic source occurs.